# How do I add text to my entry-meta to html or my php file?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add · Product 1 text to my `entry-meta` but I don't know how to add it to html or my php file. This `entry-meta` goes under the post title and goes on each post so I don't know also how to make the 1 in Product 1 change for each post.

This is what I want it to say:

By Kyle Boas · Follow: Twitter

September 21, 2014 · Product 1

but it currently says:

By Kyle Boas · Follow: Twitter

September 21, 2014

Here is the code of the `entry-header`:

```
   <p class="entry-meta">
     <span class="author_wrap">By <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
     <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Kyle Boas</span></span></span> 
     · 
     <span class="follow_links">Follow: <a href="http://twitter.com/boasish" target="_blank">Twitter</a></span> 
     <span class="date_comment"><time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-09-21T19:42:35+00:00">September 21, 2014</time></span></p></header>
```

You can see it for yourself on my website: http://boasish.com

Comment: The product part is missing in this code, so it makes sense that it's not displayed.

Comment: I know how do I add it??

Comment: Do you have product IDs or you just want to display some sort of counter?

Comment: A counter. For every article I want it to display the product article number. Kind of like how Youtube uses a counter to count how many videos you have made.

Answer (score 0):

there is no php code to output anything?

you need to add some php code to output that ....

for example change:

```
<span class="date_comment"><time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-09-21T19:42:35+00:00">September 21, 2014</time></span>
```

to

```
<span class="date_comment"><time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-09-21T19:42:35+00:00">September 21, 2014</time><? echo "Product " . $x; ?></span>
```

where $x is the number of the product you want to output ...

Comment: I know I need to add some php code, and in the example you didn't change anything.

Comment: sorry, didn't highlight the code correctly, so stackoverflow didn't display it but "run" the code ;)

Comment: I changed it - should work now. Do you get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

To show a counter of products you'd need a variable; lets say `$i`.

First it would be good to initialize the variable `$i`, which must be done **before the post loop**.

```
$x = 0;
```

Then, you increment the variable and show it:

```
<p class="entry-meta">
    <span class="author_wrap">By <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Kyle Boas</span></span></span> 
    · 
    <span class="class-for-product">Product <?php echo ++$i; ?></span>

    <span class="follow_links">Follow: <a href="http://twitter.com/boasish" target="_blank">Twitter</a></span> 
    <span class="date_comment"><time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-09-21T19:42:35+00:00">September 21, 2014</time></span>
</p>
```